# How to use both "double" functions and "single" functions from Intel MKL (cblas)

Tags: c, g++, blas, intel-mkl

The C interface to blas (I am using Intel MKL) has different functions for  operating on input data of the single datatype and the double datatype.  For example, `cblas_dgemm` vs. `cblas_sgemm`.

I wrote a program that uses these functions extensively.  I would like the user to have the option of using single precision or double precision for their calculations.  This simply means that every place where it says dgemm should be sgemm (and so forth for other functions).  I do not want to copy all the code and replace all sgemm for dgemm.  How can I most elegantly provide both functionalities to the user without having two copies of the same code?

One potential solution would be replace all instances of cblas_dgemm with cblas_gemm, and use macros to #define cblas_gemm as either cblas_dgemm or cblas_sgemm depending on a g++ compiler flag `-DDATATYPE_SINGLE` or `-DDATATYPE_DOUBLE`.  Then, there would be two different executables, with the same code base.  Is this the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't just replace the function calls by the single precision function (the argument types will have to change, too, I'd recommend defining a template class for both float and double, let's say `template <typename T> class processing`, and, write two specialization of the template class, for the places the differences matter (ie where you call the cblas routines).

Comment: You are correct, the argument types would change too, but in my proposed approach, this would only be one extra macro: `floating_point_datatype` would be #defined as either `double` or `single` at compile time.

If I were to use templates, I would have to write two specializations every place the difference matters.  I have dozens, if not hundreds, of places where it matters, and this would lead to significant code duplication.  Why do you think this is better than the macro approach?

Comment: It's not really better, I agree, but it would let you handle both classes with a unique handle -- `processing<T>`, which might be easier if someone else might use your library. I'd in fact do both specializations using `#define` magic, too, but, and that's just a matter of preference, rather have templates than carrying the 1970's Fortran naming scheme into the year 2015 by having names like `processing_float`.